# Sector determination of a nonlinearity and passivity

Tags: control-engineering, automotive-engineering, control-theory

This a not a homework or any similar task.

Regarding determine the determination of static nonlinearity, I know that one can draw two lines that contains the nonlinearity part. For instance for three cases below:

[image: three different non linearities]

The definition for sectors is
$ a \leq \frac{f(y)}{y} \leq b $ 
Where $f(y)$ is shown in figure above.

For a) I draw a straight line with slipe of 1 and one line with slope of zero and for the other nonlinearities, the sectors are marked  as figures below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The yellow area is the area that the sector should be. Regarding the sector area of the third curve. Isn't it misleading the the orange area could be accidentally interpreted as the sector area?

- How would that look like for a backlash?
- How do I calclulate the gain of those nonlinearity? Assume that 
  $gain =Sup \frac{||f(y)||_2}{||y||_2}$
- When it comes to passivity, we know that $\int_0^T y^T u \geq 0$. But cant figure that out for those system and backlash. Whatever I  do I end up with all system being passive.

Comment: ...around so. It would be wonderful if next time you could do this without external help.

Comment: I agree @peterh